# How to write pragmas in C

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, pragma

I know that `#pragmas` are compiler directives which are used to provide additional information to the compiler. My question is that, I need to write some  `#pragmas` for my project. i.e, I need to invoke some particular code when there are some particular pattern in code. Can some one throw light on this ...?

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want to do?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you need to do or what pragmas might have to do with it - describe your actual problem.

Comment: Are you asking if you can define your own `#pragma`? If so the answer is a big resounding *no*.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. What is this **particular pattern** you wish to detect to invoke the **particular code**?

Comment: I need to write my own Compiler directive with various clauses. For e.g., we have openMP compiler directives like #pragma parallel for, which is used for parallelize a 'for' loop. I need to write something similar.

Comment: Can you describe exactly what the pragma would do?

Comment: Are you sure you mean #pragma and not #define?

Comment: How in the world is this "not a real question"??

Comment: I don't see how this is not a real question? It's a question, perhaps worded strangely, but it's still a valid question.

Comment: The plural of `pragma` is not `pragmas` but `pragmata` (`pragma` is a greek work meaning "thing"). Just a fun fact for your enjoyment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write your own `#pragma`s. You must look into your compiler's handbook for which `#pragma`s are supported.

Alternatively, if your compiler allows you to modify its source code (license- and sourcecode-wise), you might hack some new ones in. Don't expect it to be a trivial task, there's usually no enduser-friendly plug-in *write-your-own-pragmas* system.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer. But don't do it too quickly, wait a bit to motivate more people to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`#pragma` is a way for compiler vendors to legally implement proprietary extensions. They are hard-coded into the compiler. (And IIRC compilers are required to ignore unknown pragmas.)

Unless you write your own compiler, you cannot create your own pragmas.